# Как оптимально делать api запросы в Битрикс

Tags: python, python-3.x, битрикс, api

Был у кого-то опыт? Поделитесь, пожалуйста.
Работаю с их crm, пытаюсь выгрузить через их апи к себе в базу все данные о наших лидах. Это будет ежедневная процедура. Но пока что трэш - на пачку лидов 50 шт нужно сделать 151 = 1 + 50*3 запроса. С учётом того, что у них ограничение 1 запрос в 0.7 секунды, а лидов 30000, руки опускаются. Документация их (так же как и структура данных) к апи оставляют желать лучшего. Кто как справлялся? Поделиьесь опытом, пожалуйста!! 
Подключаюсь через вебхуки.

Comment: На получение одного лида из API нужно сделать 3 запроса и нет возможности одним запросом получить пачку данных? Можете добавить в вопрос пример кода для отправки запроса

Comment: Нет, потому что для этого одного лида часть его данных разбросано по трем разным апи и id Лида - обязательный параметр в этих запросах, без него не работает. Поэтому сначала приходится вытаскивать из общей базы пачку 50 штук, потом разбирать по одному и добирать  ещё по 3ем апи данные

Answer (score 3):

Обратите внимание на Python-пакет [fast_bitrix24](https://pypi.org/project/fast-bitrix24/).

Эта библиотека была специально написана, чтобы в одну строку кода быстро выкачивать большие объемы из Битрикс24, используя параллельные запросы и упаковку запросов в батчи.

Чтобы выкачать все лиды:

```
import fast_bitrix24

# ниже вставьте ваш вебхук
b = fast_bitrix24.Bitrix('your_webhook_goes_here')

leads = b.get_all('crm.lead.list')
```

Вы получите список всех ваших лидов. 30000 лидов загрузятся примерно за 10-20 сек.

Comment: Вот спасибо за наводку. `bitrix24-rest` неимоверно тугая либа на больших объемах. 25к лидов тянет около 3х минут. Буду пробовать. А как у нее обстоят дела с обработкой ошибок запросов?

Comment: Пока что никак. Если на этапе конструирования запроса к серверу все прошло ОК, то запрос уходит. А если обратно от сервера приходит ошибка, то поднимается исключение на базе кода HTTP-ответа. Либо приходит пустой ответ, что может поднять исключение в коде обработки ответа. :)))))))

А дайте больше подробностей, плз - какую ошибку ожидаете и какое поведение хотите?

Comment: Да собственно если она райзает стандартные реквестовские исключения, то проблем не вижу. Только прогрессбар немного раздражает при пакетной выгрузке. Не в курсе может отключается как?

Comment: Да, я сегодня-завтра запилю отключение прогрессбара. А как со скоростью загрузки, норм?

Comment: Скорость в поряде

Comment: Кстати на счет скорости bitrix24-rest на пакетной обработке я напецдел. Тянет на много дольше, сегодня спецом проверил. Просто на кроне уже месяца 2 болтается, забыл уже на сколько она тугая

Comment: Все, добавил параметр `verbose` в `Bitrix.__init__()`, установив который в `False`, можно отключить прогрессбар: `b = fast_bitrix24.Bitrix('your_webhook_URI', verbose=False)`. Ну и написал почище обработку ошибок сервера - теперь описания ошибок в исключениях будут чуть понятнее.

Надо проапгредиться до версии 0.2.3.

Answer (score 1):

лучше думаю тебе сделать через отдельный php скрипт, который будет принимать JSON и отдавать JSON.

Для получения лидов можешь юзать это
http://bxapi.ru/src/?module_id=crm&name=CCrmLead%3A%3AGetList

Comment: Я не php-ист, толкьо python. Можно в личку напишу по поводу этого запроса? ) 
Но, во-первых, не поняла, что значит принимать JSON? В смысле JSON из параметров Filter\Select? И правильно я поняла, что в этом скрипте как-то мэтчатся разные запросы? увидела join

Answer (score 1):

для таких объемов данных я бы рекомендовал использовать готовые либы для взаимодействия с rest, есть "официальная" [битриксовая на php](https://github.com/mesilov/bitrix24-php-sdk)

для питона можете попробовать [эту](https://pypi.org/project/bitrix24-python-sdk/)

> на пачку лидов 50 шт нужно сделать 151 = 1 + 50*3 запроса.

также обратите внимание что битриксовый рест поддерживает [пакетные запросы](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/general/batch.php) таким образом за 1 запрос можно вытащить 50*50 = 2500 лидов. ограничение 2 запроса в секунду, поэтому 30к лидов можно получить за 6 секунд